# pagination in search results

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I want to do pagination in search result .i have one page and there are two table one for the searching and second for the result.

```
    <form method="get">
<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
<tr>
<td>Username</td>
<td><input type="text" name="user"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
<tr>
<th>User</th>
<th>Address</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($ft=$pge->fetch_object())
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $ft->user ?></td>
<td><?php echo $ft->address ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
<center>
<?php
$totalrecords=$totalrecords/2;
for($i=0;$i<$totalrecords;$i++)
{
?>
<a href="pagination.php?pgid=<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i+1  ?></a>
<?php
}
?>
</center>
</form>
```

by default i have applied pagination but when i want to find user details by searching i also want to do pagination in search result.
however i not done yet.this is my pagination code.

```
 require('connect.php');
 $sel="select * from submit";
 $ex=$cn->query($sel) or die($cn->error);
 //$ft=$ex->fetch_object();
 $totalrecords=$ex->num_rows;


 if(isset($_REQUEST['pgid']))
 {
   $pgid=$_REQUEST['pgid'];
   $pgn=$pgid*2;
   $pg="select * from submit limit $pgn,2";
   $pge=$cn->query($pg) or die($cn->error);

 }
 else
 {
   $pg="select * from submit limit 0,2";
   $pge=$cn->query($pg) or die($cn->error);
 }

 if(isset($_REQUEST['search']))
 {
  $u=$_REQUEST['user'];

  $searchquery="select * from submit where user like '%$u%'";
  $pge=$cn->query($searchquery) or die($cn->query);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create custom MySQL query Try this code :-

```
$pg="select * from submit where 1=1";
if(isset($_REQUEST['search']))
 {
  $u=$_REQUEST['search'];
  $pg.=" and user like '%$u%'";
 }
if(isset($_REQUEST['pgid']))
 {
   $pgid=$_REQUEST['pgid'];
   $pgn=$pgid*2;
   $pg.=" limit $pgn,2";
 }
 else
 {
   $pg.=" limit 0,2";
 }

 $pge=$cn->query($pg) or die($cn->error);
```

Comment: it doesn't work when click on search button it produce syntax error               You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'user like '%a%' limit 0,2' at line 1

Comment: plz change this line **$pg.=" and user like '%$u%'";**